# Merge Two Link List in Python error in head attribute

Tags: python-3.x

> File "merge.py", line 55, in merge_linked_lists node1=lst1.head (AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'head')
>   File "merge.py", line 55, in merge_linked_lists node1=lst1.head (AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'head')
>   File "merge.py", line 55, in merge_linked_lists node1=lst1.head (AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'head')

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.head = None

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            print(node, end=' ')
            node = node.next
        print('')

    def add_at_head(self, node):
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
        self.length += 1

    def remove_node_after(self, node):
        if node.next is not None:
            temp = node.next
            node.next = node.next.next
            temp.next = None
            self.length -= 1

    def remove_first_node(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return
        temp = self.head
        self.head = self.head.next
        temp.next = None
        self.length -= 1

    def print_backward(self):
        def print_nodes_backward(node):
            if node.next is not None:
                print_nodes_backward(node.next)
            if node is not None:
                print(node, end=' ')

        if self.head is not None:
            print_nodes_backward(self.head)
        print('')

def merge_linked_lists(lst1, lst2):

    node1=lst1.head
    node2=lst2.head
    temp=None
    if(node1 is None):
        return node2

    if(node2 is None):
        return node1

    if(node1.data <= node2.data):
        temp=node1
        node1.next=merge_linked_lists(node1.next,node2)

    else:
        temp=node2
        node2.next=merge_linked_lists(node2.next,node1)
    return temp

pass

lst11=LinkedList()
lst11.add_at_head(Node(1))
lst11.add_at_head(Node(2))
lst11.add_at_head(Node(3))

lst22=LinkedList()
lst22.add_at_head(Node(4))
lst22.add_at_head(Node(5))
lst22.add_at_head(Node(6))

merge_linked_lists(lst11,lst22)
```

> how to make lists merged using this method
>   its write (AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'head')

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do 2 things in `merge_linked_lists`. When you first call this recursive function, you supply it with 2 instances of the class `LinkedList` which have `head` attributes. Then within the function itself, you pass in `node1.next` and `node2`, both of which are of the class `Node` which do not contain `next` or `head` and so it fails.

Comment: what do you think that i should do ? with out a recursive its not done